# Styling Angular-Datatable with Bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm trying to make Angular-Datatable (https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) style like Bootstrap. So, i have the following in my angular.json file:

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"
            ]
```

But my datatable look like this:

[image]

My project can be found in GitHub: https://github.com/rlanhellas/together-admin

Comment: if you share a Stackblitz, it'll be easier to help

Comment: I edited my post with code in GitHub

Comment: where is the datatable in your project (https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xqzvb8) ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal, Inside "/src/app/usuario/usuario.component.html"

Answer (score 1):

I had to add these to the bottom of the index.html to get bootstrap styling to work for datatables:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to add all the below CDNs to resolve your styling issues. This has worked for me too...!!

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**I don't know, why we need to add this CDNs even after installing all the datatable packages and modifying angular.json file.**